# Searching an array for all matches and returning indices of the match

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to create an array that holds all of the rows where one (very large array) matches with a set of unique values. The problem is that the large array will have multiple rows where it will match and I need all of them stored in the same row of the new array.

Using a for loop to loop through each of the unique values works but is way too slow to be usable. I have been searching for a vectorized solution but have not been successful. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
    arrStart = []
    startRavel = startInforce['pol_id'].ravel()
    for policy in unique_policies:
        arrStart.append(np.argwhere(startRavel == policy))
```

The new array would have the same length as the unique values array but each element would be a list of all of the rows that match that unique value in the large array.

Sample Input would be something like this:
startRavel = [1,2,2,2,3,3]
unique_policies = [1,2,3]

Output:
arrStart = [[0], [1,2,3],[4,5]]

Comment: Can you provide some sample input and expected output?

Comment: Yeah, an example of the input would be something like this: Large Array = [1,2,2,2,3,3,4,5]   Set of ids = [ 1,2,3,4,5]  . Expected output = [ 0, [1,2,3],[4,5],6,7]

Answer (score 0):

One possible option with NumPy, similar to your but flattened in list comprehension:

```
startRavel = np.array([1,2,2,2,3,3])
unique_policies = np.array([1,2,3])

[np.argwhere(startRavel == policy).flatten() for policy in unique_policies]
#=> [array([0]), array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5])]
```

---

Alternative, using [`flatnonzero()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.flatnonzero.html):

```
[np.flatnonzero(startRavel == policy) for policy in unique_policies]
```

---

Generator version:

```
def matches_indexes(startRavel, unique_policies):
  for policy in unique_policies:
    yield np.flatnonzero(startRavel == policy)
```

Comment: This is cleaner than what I had but I do not think it is much faster since it is still looping

Comment: Added a generator version. Generator is fast, however time is taken converting the generator to a list or an np.array.

Comment: The generator solution is interesting but it still takes approx the same amount of time to build up the full output array. I could see this being a good answer in certain situations